# SignalR works only on certains browsers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, signalr

I have created the chat test application from http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc-4 and published to azure: http://joedevtestchat.azurewebsites.net/home/chat

I test accessing from multiple browsers and I get an unexpected behavior, sending messages from chrome(windows) I only can see in the same browser and android from my phone, but I don't see the messages on Firefox, IE, Safari and Opera.

On the other hand, Firefox, IE, Safari and Opera (all Windows) share the messages, but not see messages from Android and Chrome.

In a previous test, IE share messages with Chrome and Android, and not with FF, Opera, and Safari.

Please see screenshots attached. I use the last versions of every browser.

I start to work with SignalR today, so I don't know where I can start to debug to resolve this issue. Why can be the reason of this unexpected behavior?

You can test at: http://joedevtestchat.azurewebsites.net/home/chat

[image: browsers]
[image: android]

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer in the post:  [Intermittent problems with SignalR Hubs (in the Cloud) callback from Server to Client method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753853/intermittent-problems-with-signalr-hubs-in-the-cloud-callback-from-server-to-c?rq=1)

I have selected two instances for the websites in my azure configuration. When set to 1 instance the problem was solved.

Comment: Yep, you'll need to configure scale-out if you wish to run your SignalR application in a web-farm environment. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-in-signalr