# SignalR only Working when both person is on Different type of browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, signalr

I am having some bad time here. I have a chat application. Our async functionality using signalR only works when both person are in different types of browser. I need some expert advice here. I can show code if required. Please let me know if anyone face same issue. I tried to log signalr in browser. Still logs only show when both person in different type browser ( But I can see connection started successful response in XHR tab). No log when both are in different type browser from different machine. We are using azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had multiple web role instances in azure. It was the problem.
Found it from here.

[Intermittent problems with SignalR Hubs (in the Cloud) callback from Server to Client method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753853/intermittent-problems-with-signalr-hubs-in-the-cloud-callback-from-server-to-c?rq=1)